# Matlab OOP: How to update properties of an object

Tags: matlab, oop

```
classdef PortfolioX 
       properties 
          name; 
          anzahl=0; 
          myValue=0; 
          handeln; 
          preis=0; 
       end 

  function [this, portfolio1] = setAnzahl(this, portfolio1, AktienAnzahl, AktienPreis) 
  .... 
  this.preis = AktienPreis; 
  portfolio1.value = AktienAnzahl;
   ... 
   end
end



function StartTrading(DDD, Portfolio) 
%if text.mat 
load test.mat 
%end 

%Aktie = DDD; 
DDD.handeln = 'buy'; 
    %Anzahl an Aktien die gehandelt werden und deren aktueller Preis 
    [DDD, Portfolio] = setAnzahl(DDD, Portfolio, 200, 5); 

    save test.mat 
load test.mat
```

Now i do following:

1. Construct Object DDD and Object Portfolio
2. I Start `StartTrading(DDD, Portfolio)`
3. Result: Object DDD and Portfolio have the same propertie values as
   constructed.

**What i expected was**, that they had updated values (preis = 50 and handeln = 'buy').
What is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: maybe you can consider to declare values as dependent property, which is automatically updated each time it is retrieved. See more here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-access-methods.html?refresh=true#bsxanmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a value object in MATLAB. When you pass these objects to functions, a copy is created for them. These copies are modified by you inside the function. Unless you return these copies back, you only have the unmodified original objects outside the function.

You can either return the objects from the function and assign them back to the same variables or use handle objects by inheriting from handle. See documentation comparing handle and value class at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html

Comment: Hey there guys! I read all about Handles and Values, tried both ways. No difference at all. Could you give me more details on how to make MY CODE work? That would be very nice of you.

Comment: Change your function signature to function [DDD, portfolio] = StartTrading(DDD, Portfolio). When calling supply the same lhs arguments as the rhs.

Comment: It worked. It makes sense. I needed to say where it should be saved. Thank you and have a AWESOME week! (sadly cant give you +1, as i dont have 15 rep. :D